# No consigo recibir el valor desde ajax a php y luego hacer un insert

Tags: ajax

Código html:

```
<input type="datetime" name="fechaEntrada" id="fechaEntrada">
<input type="datetime" name="fechaSalida" id="fechaSalida">
```

Ajax:

```
var fechaEntrada = document.getElementById('fechaEntrada').value;
var fechaSalida = document.getElementById('fechaSalida').value;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/insertar.php",
    data: {fechaEntrada, fechaSalida},
    dataType: "html",
    asycn: false, // el error que cometí de sintaxis, es async
    success: function() {
       alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$fechaEntrada = $_POST['fechaEntrada'];
$fechaSalida = $_POST['fechaSalida'];
$ins = new PDO("mysql:dbname=reservas;host=127.0.0.1", "root", "");
$insert = $ins->prepare("INSERT INTO `registro` (`entrada`, `salida`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$insert->execute([date_parse($fechaEntrada), date_parse($fechaSalida)]);
```

Resultado base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no pasas correctamente los datos mediante ajax. Comprueba antes que nada que a PHP le llega la información esperada en `$fechaEntrada` y en `$fechaSalida`. Si no llega nada puede que el error esté en lo siguiente:

```
var fechaEntrada = document.getElementById('fechaEntrada').value;
var fechaSalida = document.getElementById('fechaSalida').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/insertar.php",
        data:{fechaEntrada,fechaSalida}, // <<<--- ERROR
        dataType:"html",
        asycn:false, //el error que cometí de sintaxis, es async
        success: function(){
           alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
        }
```

Donde está marcado como "ERROR" estas pasadon un "objeto" del estilo json. Ahí siempre tiene que haber "clave":"valor".

Lo correcto sería pasar siempre algo parecido a:

```
{
  "clave1":"valor",
  "clave2":"valor"
}
```

Otra cosa sería si quisieras pasar un array:

```
{
  "indice":["valor1", "valor2", "valor3", ... ] 
}
```

Para pasar correctamente la información:

```
var infoParaEnviar: {entrada: fechaEntrada, salida: fechaSalida};

$.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
        url: "php/insertar.php",
        data: infoParaEnviar,
        dataType:"text",
        asycn:false, //el error que cometí de sintaxis, es async
        success: function(){
           alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
        }
});
```

En el PHP solo tendrías que cambiar:

```
$fechaEntrada=$_POST['entrada'];
$fechaSalida=$_POST['salida'];
```

Pruebalo y me dices. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero sigo añadiendo 0... a la base de datos, creo que el problema está o a la hora de recibir o de enviar los datos desde el php

Comment: @YasielHernández cuando lees la variable `$_POST` ¿qué es lo que lees exactamente?

Answer (score 1):

Hay que pasar un objeto JSON.

```js
var fechaEntrada = document.getElementById('fechaEntrada').value; //probar .valueAsDate
var fechaSalida = document.getElementById('fechaSalida').value; // probar .valueAsDate

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/insertar.php",
    data: { entrada: fechaEntrada, salida: fechaSalida }
})
```

```html
 <input type="datetime" name="fechaEntrada" id="fechaEntrada">
 <input type="datetime" name="fechaSalida" id="fechaSalida">
```

Por lo demás el PHP debería de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO**
El problema estaba a la hora de hacer el insert a la base de datos
PHP:

```
    <?php
$fechaEntrada=$_POST['entrada'];
$fechaSalida=$_POST['salida'];

    $ins = new PDO("mysql:dbname=reservas;host=127.0.0.1","root","");
        $insert=$ins->prepare("INSERT INTO `registro` (`entrada`, `salida`) VALUES (CAST('". $fechaEntrada ."' AS DATE),CAST('". $fechaSalida ."' AS DATE) )");
        $insert->execute();
    ?>
```

AJAX / JavaScript proporcionado por @Jonathan en los comentarios:

```
var fechaEntrada = document.getElementById('fechaEntrada').value;
    var fechaSalida = document.getElementById('fechaSalida').value;

    var infoParaEnviar=
    {
        entrada: fechaEntrada,
        salida: fechaSalida
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/insertar.php",
        data: infoParaEnviar,
        dataType: "text",
        asycn: false, //el error que cometí de sintaxis, es async
        success: function () {
            alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
        }
    });
```